# fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found when building an iOS app on PhoneGap 3.x

Tags: ios, cordova, xcode5, phonegap-build, command-line-tool

I installed NodeJS and phonegap to start working on version 3.0. The first time I tried, I successfully run the sample app on the iOS simulator. Later I try to replace the contents of the /www directory on the Xcode project and it never runs again.

Since that I have tried to build the sample "Hello World" a lot of times but I always got this error:

```
    In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:13:10: fatal error: 'assert.h' file not found
#include <assert.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

I already tried reinstalling PhoneGap with the npm tool. I also tried reinstalling ios-sim. When I open the project on Xcode and try to run it on the simulator I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved it by reinstalling XCode. I was using XCode 5.0.2 over MacOS Mavericks.